# C# or C++ - Good Resource for an Overview on Windows Graphics - 2D, drawing pixels directly

Tags: c#, c++, windows, graphics

I have this odd little lifesim program I've been working on that involves data in a 2d array. This was never supposed to be a big thing, and I initially looked at a few snapshots of it by just writing it out to an external bitmap, pixel by pixel, which I then open and look at. This doesn't give me any sort of live update to the screen. This is a horrible way to do this, and in trying to implement drawing this directly in a window, I want to do this correct and efficiently the first time.

I did some searching and found [bitblt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which will let me draw a whole rectangle at a time, but all of my graphics experience being limited to things like WPF, a lot of the terminology is lost on me. I don't know what format my data should be in order to hand it to this function as a bitmap. In reading around msdn I find references to things like DC, etc, more things I haven't yet learned about.

I don't need to know lots about Windows graphics API or .NET's drawing framework. I don't want to learn a bunch of DirectX. I want to make a Window of a specific dimension and I want to be able to set the RGB value of each of those pixels as I see fit. No drawings shapes or anything, just pixels. But I also don't want to do it one pixel at a time, a separate system call for each, because even a lame programmer like myself knows how terribly inefficient that is. Does anyone know if a good resource that will give a simple explanation of graphics in Windows and will let me do this? MSDN is great for looking things up, but it's a bit much if you're trying to learn something from scratch.

C# is preferable because the lifesim in written in it, but I don't have any qualms about rewriting it in C++ if there's a good reason for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) class in WPF and see if it fits your purposes.

[A tutorial](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/wpf-workings/527-writeablebitmap.html)

All you would have to do is keep the data in the 2D array and write it to the WriteableBitmap. Set the WriteableBitmap as the image source of a WPF Image and you're done.

Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: I'm currently reading through the tutorial, thanks. I'll let you know in a few minutes how it goes.

Comment: I need to do some playing around to see if I can get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is use LockBits to lock up your image data, and then manipulate your image as an array. Here's a great tutorial by Bob Powell:

https://web.archive.org/web/20121203144033/http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm

Otherwise, if speed is not a concern, you can use the GetPixel and SetPixel methods. These are horribly slow though, but will work in a managed environment.

Comment: Speed is a concern; in future versions of this program I'd like to draw a lot of pixels to the screen, very quickly, with minimal cpu usage. You answer seems to act the same as the other, but the syntax is different. I will need to do some playing around here

Comment: LockBits is probably as quick as it gets in this environment. Otherwise you have to opt for DX or something.